# Accessing objects from a c# console app externally

Tags: c#, output, console-application

I'm a new junior dev and working on my first solo project. For that im creating a c# console app for automated word document creation. The plan is to integrate the app in different projects and different invironments thats why it should be an stand alone solution. But in order to give it a little more felxability and versatility I want the app to give some output.

Because of the different invironments the app should be useable with e.g. a python script aswell. What would be the best practice to do so??? especially if you want to give diffrent outputs depending on the use case???

A litte example:
I'm getting an json object with all the information to create a word document. In the stand alone solution I don't need an output (it only creats a word doc and pfd). But if I want to use the app it in an wpf UI project were i want preview and live update functionality it would be nice to have access to the created objects.
In order to achieve this would I work with a **return value** (exit code) and (depending on the code) create the desired objects again, or would I embed it as a **library** and just call all the normal functionality, or could i even do something like an **out value** or **complex return value** (like string[]) to return a serialized object?

a.)

```
static int Main(string[] args)
{
   //do something
   return *code for decision making*
}
```

b.) create library

c.)

```
static void Main(string[] args, out string[] output)
{
   //do something
   output = *serialized object(s)*
}
```

or

```
static string[] Main(string[] args)
{
   //do something
   return *serialized object(s)*
}
```

Comment: This is a little unclear, what is it you actually want to do?

Comment: access an object which was created in an console app from a diffrent application.

Comment: Access it from 2 different processes? or share a library between 2 applications at design time ?

Comment: Ideally i would have access to an object in 2 diffrent processes at runtime. but I think it would also be fine to send them between 2 processes when needed. like i said I'm a new and not 100% sure what would be best practice so maybe there is even a 3 solution I'm not seeing

Comment: Usually these days (in .net) you would just serialize the object and use some sort IPC. You could in theory share memory, with something like a *Memory Mapped File*. Though for most applications the former would be more common unless you had a specific use case

Comment: I took a quick look at c# ipc and it looks preety much like what i was looking for. or there are a bunch of ways to acive what i was looking for. Would be nice to upvote your comment as solution but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/main-and-command-args/) MSDN article, the `Main()` method in C# can only have these signatures:

```cs
public static void Main();
public static int Main();
public static void Main(string[] args);
public static int Main(string[] args);
public static async Task Main();
public static async Task<int> Main();
public static async Task Main(string[] args);
public static async Task<int> Main(string[] args);
```

This shows that it's impossible to return data about an object from the `Main()` method in C#.

However, you can return data about an object for another environment/program to handle by printing the data about that object to the console output stream in a format like JSON. From your other environment (ex: Python) you can read the console output stream of your C# program as a string and then parse it.

Comment: thanks for the info. so that means solution c.) is impossible. because writing it dose not give me any errors. but i gues i can't access the return/output value properly?

Comment: You actually should get an error. The reason you are not getting an error is because you probably already defined a valid `Main()` entry point signature in your source code. Since that is defined, your other overload of the `Main()` method (example C) will never be run. Technically speaking, you can actually access the return value of your overloaded method, however, you can't return it in your valid `Main()` method.